# Code 400 while sending POST to the backend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http-status-code-400

So i am currently working on a simple scholl project and i want to store the specific data to my database, but i recieve eror 400.

I tried changing the path, making a catch error setting breakpoints but it never gets to that part, i tried resolving this with my friends and maybe trying to ask AI but still it failed to deliver.

So this is the current javascript funtion im haveing a problem with

```
async function toggleMovieInList(event) {
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    const movieId = parseInt(overlay.dataset.movieId);
    const isInList = event.currentTarget.dataset.inList === "true";
    let response;

    // Fetch the current user's ID
    const userIdResponse = await fetch('/Browse?handler=UserId');

    if (userIdResponse.ok) {
        var userId = await userIdResponse.json();
        console.log('userId:', userId);
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to fetch userId');
        return;
    }

    if (isInList) {
        // If the movie is in the list, remove it
        response = await fetch('/Browse?handler=RemoveFromWatchlist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ userId, movieId }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    } else {
        // If the movie is not in the list, add it
        response = await fetch('/Browse?handler=AddToWatchlist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ userId, movieId }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await response.text();
        console.error(`Failed to toggle movie with ID ${movieId} in list. Server responded with: ${errorMessage}`);
        return;
    }


    if (response.ok) {
        const iconElement = event.currentTarget.querySelector('i');
        if (isInList) {
            iconElement.classList.remove('fa-solid', 'fa-check');
            iconElement.classList.add('fas', 'fa-plus');
            event.currentTarget.dataset.inList = "false";
        } else {
            iconElement.classList.remove('fas', 'fa-plus');
            iconElement.classList.add('fa-solid', 'fa-check');
            event.currentTarget.dataset.inList = "true";
        }
        console.error(`Failed to toggle movie with ID ${movieId} in list`);
    }
}
```

And here is the backend code, i think that the urls for handler methods should be alright because the first method is working but the 2nd method isnt.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using AquariumApp.UtilitiesHelpers;

namespace AquariumApp.Pages
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    public class BrowseModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public class MovieData
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public int MovieId { get; set; }
        }

        public BrowseModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetUserId()
        {
            int userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID") ?? default;
            return new JsonResult(userId);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddToWatchlistAsync([FromBody] MovieData data)
        {
            try
            {
                int userId = data.UserId;
                int movieId = data.MovieId;

                using (OleDbConnection connection = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UsersMyList (User_ID, MovieShowID) VALUES (?, ?)", connection);

                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("User_ID", userId));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MovieShowID", movieId));

                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }

                return new OkResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("An error occurred while adding to watchlist: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRemoveFromWatchlistAsync([FromBody] MovieData data)
        {
            try
            {
                int userId = data.UserId;
                int movieId = data.MovieId;

                using (OleDbConnection connection = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM UsersMyList WHERE User_ID = ? AND MovieShowID = ?", connection);

                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("User_ID", userId));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MovieShowID", movieId));

                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }

                return new OkResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("An error occurred while removing from watchlist: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I aplogise for badly formated question, I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: According to [BadRequestObjectResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0): _An ObjectResult that when executed will produce a Bad Request (400) response._

Comment: You may consider using a [different overload for OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-oledb-oledbparameter-ctor(system-string-system-data-oledb-oledbtype)) (ex: `command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("!User_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = userId);`)

Comment: Tried that but still it doesn't work, I think the error is in the js part. It doesn't even get to the point of going into the method..

Comment: Did you had the chance to check console in which line you are getting the error? Does your controller get hitted?

Comment: I chekced the console i have this.
       
        
        POST https://localhost:7271/Browse?handler=AddToWatchlist 400
toggleMovieInList @ Overlay.js:86
Overlay.js:97  Failed to toggle movie with ID 502356 in list. Server responded with: 
toggleMovieInList @ Overlay.js:

I also tried to set breakpoints in the above code (probably what you mean by controller sry i am new to all this) I set breakpoints at the start and at the end of the function but it doesnt stop here, so I think the issue is with the javascript itself, so like it doesn't communicate with that "function"/controller.

Comment: Also the error code for the server responded with: is blank which tells me that server didn't respond so maybe he wasn't engaged at all... I rly want to make this work, sorry for bad editing/replies.

Comment: How this `toggleMovieInList` function has been invoked? Can you share within your question?